# Displaying data from table in modals using reactjs, localStorage and state (traversing)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Ive been trying to get data from a table to a modal in ReactJS, trying as in trying to get it to work with minimal effort. I think I understand how Components work ok. But when displaying data in the modal I want the component to first go through the list and remove 'selected' class on the rest of the rows and then display the selected row. Right now my modal only displays the last row, regardless of where I click.

```
    var BoatRow =  React.createClass({displayName: 'BoatRow',
    handleClick: function(event){
          this.setState({className:'selected'});
        },
    getInitialState: function(){
        return (
         {
          className:'!selected',
            }
        )
    },
    render:function(){

        var listed = this.state.className ? 'selected' : 
        localStorage.setItem('boat', JSON.stringify({
                         name:this.props.boat.Name,
                        //some data
                    }));

        return (

        React.DOM.tr({className:this.state.className},
                      React.DOM.td(null, this.props.boat.Name),
               //rest of table row data
                    React.DOM.button({type: "button", 'data-toggle': "modal", 'data-target': "#modalContent", onClick:this.handleClick
                        }, "Select" ) 
                )
            )
        )
    }
});
```

Im first going through the JSON object and pushing it to an array.

```
    var AllBoatList = React.createClass({displayName: 'AllBoatList',
    render: function(){
    var rows = [];
    var lastAvailable = null;
    this.props.boats.forEach(function(boat, i){
        if(boat.Availability !== 0){    
            rows.push(BoatRow({boat:boat, key:boat.id}));
          }

      });
    return(
            React.DOM.table({id:"boat-table"},
              //table head
                    )
                ), 
                React.DOM.tbody(null, rows)
            )
        );
    }
   });

   var data = [{ 
        "Name": "Boat Name",
        "id": "1"
      }, //rest of Json data
      }
    ]

React.render(AllBoatList({boats:data}), 
            document.getElementById('all-boats')
        );
```

And this is where the modal data gets displayed.

```
    var Boats = require(['./assets/src/scripts/boats']);

    var BoatModal = React.createClass({displayName: 'BoatModal',
      getInitialState: function(){
    return {
      value: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('boat'))
      }
      console.log(this.state.value);
  },
  render:function(){
    return (
    React.DOM.div({className: "DisplayContainer"}, 
      React.DOM.p(null, 
        this.state.value
        )
      )
    )
  }

   });

React.render(BoatModal({}), document.getElementById('modal-body')
  );
```

The components work fine displaying the table and selecting the correct row, changing classes. Im only having problems where the data displayed on the modal is not my selection, but always the last row. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I've got it working finally. I dont know if I fully understand this yet, but I had to move all onClick events to the event handler. Modal works with correct data, with this change

```
var BoatRow =  React.createClass({displayName: 'BoatRow',
    handleClick: function(event){
          this.setState({className:'selected'});
          //this is where storage should happen
          localStorage.setItem('boat', JSON.stringify({
                "Name":this.props.boat.Name
           //adding this line fixed it
            })).bind(this.props.boat.Name);

         console.log("storage written");

        },
    getInitialState: function(){
        return (
         {
          className:'!selected'
            }
        )
    },
    render:function(){

        var listed = this.state.className ? '!selected' : 'selected'
    ...
```